# Can Apache's URL redirection send a request to both original URL and rewritten URL?

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, mod-rewrite

I would like to use Apache's URL redirection to match a URL and forward it's request to another URL. Simple enough, I know. But, I'd like the originally requested URL to continue to be called in addition the rewritten URL.

Is this possible using Apache's URL rewriting facilities? Or is URL rewriting restricted to always replacing the original URL with the rewritten URL?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible using just Apache.  In all my reading of the documentation I've never seen a way to do it.

In particular, mod_rewrite won't do it.  With mod_rewrite you can change and redirect the request just about any way you want, but there's still always only one request.

What you'd probably have to do is put some kind of a script or proxy in front of Apache, to duplicate the request.  But I guess my question then is, what result will be returned to the user?  They sent just one request, they can't get two results back.

Comment: Thanks - the suggestion to handle it via a script or proxy is the way I'll go.